# 404 error when I refresh page from browser in my single page application

Tags: java, spring

I got the 404 Exception when I refresh the page from a browser in my single page application. I am using the Spring and Hibernate and I want to reload the same page by hitting refresh.

Comment: Is your web application still running?  It sounds like it's dead.

Comment: 404 returned by the server, so ideally it should be up

Comment: the title was not clear and still is not, lol :)

Answer (score 0):

Routing using javascript will make use of **History API Pushstate**, it will be seen as if you have been routed to a another page, but when you refresh the page, it is only the client which knows the routes and server wouldn't even recognize these routes so it signals a **404**.

When you are using a client side routing, considering for example `index.html` is your entry point for the application, all the server routes need to hit only `index.html` inorder to avoid 404.

I strongly recommend using an API and a client code, integration of both will actually mislead when you are redirecting all requests to `index.html`